# DLL that holds HTTP connection within itself

Tags: http, dll, connection

Is there possibility, that a C# written DLL could hold a HTTP connection as long as it can (till server timeout)? If external application would use DLL's functions, could I hold the connection (and reopen it when lost by invoking one of its methods) between this DLL's calls in this DLL?

Comment: Do you mean keeping it open even though no application is actually using the DLL?

Comment: Using means invoking its method. I mean that the DLL is loaded, but no methods are invoked at the moment. So maybe it would possible when DLL is loaded, there was call for DLL's constructor (manual, just to open connection) and it holds connection, but no method is called at the moment. Maybe there is workaround by using Windows DLL's, like wininet.dll.